# How to fix node-pre-gyp / realm install error on apple silicon?

Tags: node.js, npm, docker-compose, realm, apple-m1

In a dockerized react-native app, on a M1 chip mac, im having an issue running yarn install. It seems to be related to realm (v10.2.0). the terminal im trying to run this from is bash. im not sure if the terminal in vscode can be switched to the alt-rosetta-terminal

Local Environment:

- OS: big sur (11.3)
- Chip: m1
- node: 10.20.1
- python --version =  2.7.16 (present out of the box, never manually installed)
- python3 --version = 3.9.5 (believe i installed through the terminal)
- nvm (installed through rosetta-terminal)
- python3 uninstalled and reinstalled with brew in rosetta terminal, and linked in .bash_profile

dockerized app:

- React native: v63.4
- node: 15.3.0-alpine3.10

Things ive tried:

- updating to realm v10.4.1 (supposedly this was a fix for the m1 - failed with error code 127, no other details)
- downgrading local node version to node 8 or 10 (supposedly this was a fix as well - failed with same error as below)
- adding python PATH variable
- running `npm config set python /usr/local/bin/python3` from both inside the project root, and also from inside app/node_modules/realm/

Not sure if i need to mdify the node version in the container to 8/10 since thats apparently that only version compatible with m1

heres my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

This is the error:

> error /app/node_modules/realm: Command failed. Exit code: 1 Command:
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build -j 8
> ${npm_config_arch:+--target_arch=${npm_config_arch}} Arguments:
> Directory: /app/node_modules/realm Output: node-pre-gyp info it worked
> if it ends with ok node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.15.0
> node-pre-gyp info using node@15.3.0 | linux | arm64 node-pre-gyp WARN
> Using request for node-pre-gyp https download  node-pre-gyp info check
> checked for
> "/app/node_modules/realm/compiled/napi-v4_linux_arm64/realm.node" (not
> found) node-pre-gyp http GET
> https://static.realm.io/node-pre-gyp/napi-v4/realm-v10.2.0/realm-v10.2.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz
> node-pre-gyp http 404
> https://static.realm.io/node-pre-gyp/napi-v4/realm-v10.2.0/realm-v10.2.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz
> node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404):
> https://static.realm.io/node-pre-gyp/napi-v4/realm-v10.2.0/realm-v10.2.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz
> node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for realm@10.2.0 and
> node@15.3.0 (node-v88 ABI, musl) (falling back to source compile with
> node-gyp)  node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball
> https://static.realm.io/node-pre-gyp/napi-v4/realm-v10.2.0/realm-v10.2.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz
> gyp info it worked if it ends with ok gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
> gyp info using node@15.3.0 | linux | arm64 gyp info ok  gyp info it
> worked if it ends with ok gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2 gyp info using
> node@15.3.0 | linux | arm64 gyp ERR! find Python  gyp ERR! find Python
> Python is not set from command line or npm configuration gyp ERR! find
> Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON gyp ERR!
> find Python checking if "python3" can be used gyp ERR! find Python -
> "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error gyp ERR! find Python
> checking if "python" can be used gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is
> not in PATH or produced an error gyp ERR! find Python checking if
> "python2" can be used gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH
> or produced an error gyp ERR! find Python  gyp ERR! find Python
> ********************************************************** gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python. gyp ERR!
> find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
> gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options: gyp
> ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
> gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm) gyp ERR!
> find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON gyp ERR! find Python
>
> - Set the npm configuration variable python: gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable" gyp ERR! find Python
>   For more information consult the documentation at: gyp ERR! find
>   Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation gyp ERR! find
>   Python ********************************************************** gyp
>   ERR! find Python  gyp ERR! configure error  gyp ERR! stack Error:
>   Could not find any Python installation to use gyp ERR! stack     at
>   PythonFinder.fail
>   (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:302:47) gyp ERR! stack
>   at PythonFinder.runChecks
>   (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:136:21) gyp ERR! stack
>   at PythonFinder.
>   (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:179:16) gyp ERR! stack
>   at PythonFinder.execFileCallback
>   (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:266:16) gyp ERR! stack
>   at exithandler (node:child_process:316:5) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:328:5) gyp ERR! stack
>   at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (node:internal/child_process:275:12) gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT
>   (node:internal/child_process:467:16) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21)
>   gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.25-linuxkit gyp ERR! command
>   "/usr/local/bin/node" "/app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--jobs=8"
>   "--module=/app/node_modules/realm/compiled/napi-v4_linux_arm64/realm.node"
>   "--module_name=realm"
>   "--module_path=/app/node_modules/realm/compiled/napi-v4_linux_arm64"
>   "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=4"
>   "--node_napi_label=napi-v4" gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/realm gyp
>   ERR! node -v v15.3.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2 gyp ERR! not ok
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! build error  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed
>   to execute '/usr/local/bin/node
>   /app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure
>   --fallback-to-build --jobs=8 --module=/app/node_modules/realm/compiled/napi-v4_linux_arm64/realm.node
>   --module_name=realm --module_path=/app/node_modules/realm/compiled/napi-v4_linux_arm64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=4 --node_napi_label=napi-v4' (1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.
>   (/app/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose
>   (node:internal/child_process:1055:16) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (node:internal/child_process:288:5) node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux
>   5.10.25-linuxkit node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/app/node_modules/realm/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install"
>   "--fallback-to-build" "-j" "8" node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
>   /app/node_modules/realm node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v15.3.0 node-pre-gyp
>   ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.15.0 node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok  Failed to
>   execute '/usr/local/bin/node
>   /app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure
>   --fallback-to-build --jobs=8
>
> ERROR: 1

Comment: The version numbers included in your question are quite old - Realm 10.2 was from Dec 2 2020, and 10.4 was Dec 10th. How about using a current version? Also, your python appears to be out of date, did you update that? Keep in mind that as you install newer versions, they also update your data file so you'll need a newer version of Realm Studio to read them. DO NOT install 10.8 as there isn't a compatible Realm Studio yet. Stop at 10.7.7. Also, are you using cocoapods? If so, include your cocoapods version (pod --version).

Comment: running python3 --version outputs v3.9.5, but thats on my machine. is that where this container is looking for python? it sounds like i might need to configure the python path in the node-gyp dependency. nnot sure how to go about that because it seems an issue with realm-js itself (which doesnt even go up to 10.8, the latest release looks to be 10.5) what do you mean by updating data file after installing newer versions? @Jay

Comment: Sorry - I was referring to the RealmSwift SDK. As you get newer versions of Realm, the actual structure of the data is updated in the file itself and in some cases you may loose backward compatibility without other updates. In other words if you install Realm Studio 11.0 and open a 10.4 SDK file, it will update it to something later than 10.4. Therefore you will also need to update your SDK to match. e.g. When updating any piece, in general, all pieces need to be updated.

Comment: Yes, 10.5 is current for js  - note that *NOTE: Bump file format version to 22. NO DOWNGRADE PATH IS AVAILABLE.* which is what I was referring to in the above comment about a newer version updating the file. As far as the error goes, I think you need Python 2 installed, not 3. Haven't tried this but off the top of my head you may need to install it using Rosetta with homebrew.

Comment: python 2 (v2.7.16) comes installed on mac out of the box...so now what? @Jay

Comment: Yes but you said you had Python 3 in your comment. Do you have both installed? well, I am not familiar with docker but I do know that Realm installs and works on M1 out of the box (I am running it now) but there are other variables - like how did you get Python3? Do you have 2? Is this a homebrew install or something else? Lots of variables. I would suggest including as much of that as possible in the question to future readers can easily locate those points instead of reading through all the comments.

Comment: i dont get why `python --version` gives me 2.7.16 and `python3 --version` gives me v3.9.5...yet in the error logs it says it cant find either. so do i just need to set the path variable? if so, what file & location do i do that? @Jay

Comment: @Jay is my post edit sufficient information?

Comment: Yes. It looks like there's enough info. If you have Realm 10.4 installed, is the error still referencing 10.2 per the question? Also, did you try the Realm install/integration through HomeBrew?

Comment: do i need realm installed locally? this is a dockerized project, im running yarn install through the docker shell, and this error is occurring during that process, so im not sure i have it installed. its definitely not installed locally. and no, the error i get during install after changing the package.json version of realm to 10.4.1 is `error /app/node_modules/realm: Command failed.
Exit code: 127
Command: prebuild-install -r napi || cmake-js build
Arguments: 
Directory: /app/node_modules/realm` @Jay

Comment: I think there are just too many variables here. While I know this isn't the base of the project, my suggestion to start with is to build a brand new XCode project. Then implement Realm into the project and ensure that part works. I am suggesting that to ensure your OS and at least XCode are stable. So, if that works, then build a separate applicaton with docker and ensure that works. What I am doing here is isolating the variables until one of them fails. Just a thought...